# Relative import works with from but fails with import

Tags: python, import

I need to use a relative import in python, so I do:

```
from .MyModule import MyClass
```

and it works :)

However sometimes I don't want to explicitly import `MyClass`, but instead import `MyModule` and access my class by doing `MyModule.MyClass`

So I would love to do:

```
import .MyModule

my_instance = MyModule.MyClass()
```

But it appears that putting the dot after `import`  is an invalid syntax, even though it is valid after `from`

I want to keep the access of `MyClass` as part of `MyModule`, so I'm forced to do `MyModule.MyClass` and at the same time I need do a relative import of `MyModule`

How can I achieve that

Comment: does `from . import MyModule` work?

Comment: @Arne yes. that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: hmm, I can't find a good dupe, so I'll just add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative import syntax requires a `from` statement in order to work. If the accessed module is in the same folder, the dot is the only argument that it  needs:

```py
from . import MyModule

my_instance = MyModule.MyClass()  # works
```

See [the syntax definition in pep328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision)  for a full breakdown of the rules, with your intuition of how an import should work being mentioned at the bottom as "not usable".